# How to subtract all items from an array in linear order in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been able to get the sum of all items using the following code:

```
var totalPrice = [60,40];

var total = 0;

   for (var i  = 0; i < totalPrice.length; i++){

      total  += totalPrice[i];

   }
```

I then tried to subtract all items of the array doing the following:

```
 totalPrice = [60,40];

var total = 0;

   for (var i  = 0; i < totalPrice.length; i++){

      total  -= totalPrice[i];

   }
```

This gave me a negative and incorrect output.

How would I subtract all items in an array so that in this example, total would be equal to 20.

Comment: This is more of a maths question, than a programming question. Simply don’t start at `0` as the total value. Start at the first array element and iterate from index `1` onwards.

Comment: "subtracting all items in an array" does not mean anything. Subtract what from what? Once you answer this question to yourself, you will be able to fix your program.

Comment: This is more than likely not possible.  The way you could try is, find the *maximum* value in the array.  Then sum up all the other values, but if that sum is more than the maximum, you are going to end up with a negative number after all the subtraction is done.

Comment: George that is a pretty good idea and seems to be the only way that one might come out with a positive result. After some thinking I have realized that to subtract all numbers in an array will more than likely lead to a negative outcome. Ones best hope would be to find the greatest value and then subtract all other numbers from that. Whereas addition above 0 always leads to a positive outcome, subtraction above 0 can and will most likely lead to the negative.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're not trying to subtract *all* items from 0, you're trying to subtract all items *except the first* from the first. This would be a nice place to use `reduce`:

```js
const totalPrice = [60, 40];
const total = totalPrice.reduce((a, b) => a - b);
console.log(total);
```

Using a `for` loop, you would have to initialize `total` to the first element, and iterate from the second element onwards:

```js
const totalPrice = [60, 40];
let total = totalPrice[0];
for (var i = 1; i < totalPrice.length; i++) {
  total -= totalPrice[i];
}
console.log(total);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The only issue I see with this is that in this instance you knew how many numbers were in my array. But what I am trying to do, is loop through a much larger array that I don't know how many items are in it and I would like to subtract them all. How could I loop through the array and subtract all items?

Comment: Assume I use a sort algorithm to get all the numbers from greater to smaller.

Comment: But from what you posted, it looks like you *don't* want to `subtract all items` - it seemed like you wanted to subtract *all but the first item* from the first item, in which case the code will work regardless of the length of the array (as long as it has at least one element)

Comment: Yes you are correct, not all items, every item after the first and largest number. 
So if I had numbers from 1-10, it would go like this: 10-9-8-7-6-5-4-3-2-1

Comment: Then, as I said, the code should work regardless of the length of the array (using either `reduce` or the `for` method)

Comment: The only issue here if it's an empty array, otherwise both method would works if there is at least one element in the array.

Comment: I've been thinking about this further and I have to disagree with you CertainPerformance. I am indeed subtracting all numbers except for the very last one. In my example, 60 gets subtracted from 40, which results in 20. The only number there that did not go through any further subtractions, was the last one, 40, because it was the smallest, and the last item of the array.

Comment: @QuestForMastery It's not clear what you're asking. You first said you wanted to subtract all items, and then showed an example where all but the last item was subtracted from the first item. If that's not what you want, please clarify your question

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned, you don't want to end up with negative result and want to do subtraction in linear order, you should make sure that first item of Array is larger than the sum of all other items in the Array.

And also store the first item of Array in total as below.

```
 totalPrice = [60,40];

 var total = totalPrice[0];

 for (var i  = 1; i < totalPrice.length; i++){
     total  -= totalPrice[i];
 }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It helped, but it would help further if you gave an example of what you stated. Luckily for you the numbers were already sorted from greater to smaller. I wonder how you would sort the numbers from greater to smaller, and then do the subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the arguments object when there are numerous numbers passed onto the function:

```
function (){
    let total = arguments[0];
    for (let i=1 ; i<arguments.length ; i++){
        total -= arguments[i];
    }

    return total;
}
```